# How to read a Long number from application.yml

Tags: java, spring

The application.yml file has a Long type setting:

```
producer.init-delay: 15000
```

It is used in this method:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 25000, initialDelay = "#{new Long('${producer.init-delay}')}")
public produce() {}
```

Take an example from the question:[Spring @Value TypeMismatchException:...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42733067/spring-value-typemismatchexceptionfailed-to-convert-value-of-type-java-lang-s/42735568#42735568)

But I have this code gives an error:

```
Incompatible types. Found: 'java.lang.String', required: 'long'
```

Comment: On a sidenote: the c'tor `Long(long)` is deprecated. You may want to use the factory method. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49904830/create-a-new-integer-object-that-holds-the-value-1/) for details (Disclaimer: I wrote the accepted answer to this question).

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/63146218/9050514

Comment: You can use @Value for the field but you can't use this field in your annotation parameter, because the annotation parameter should be set in compilation time duration.

Comment: To the question: I am not able to find the relevant JLS, but the values of an annotation must be compile-time constants. Thus if `initialDelay` is defined as `int`, it must be assigned a value of type `int` that is known at compile-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) of the `@Scheduled`, `initialDelay` must be of type `long` and you have it as `String`.

Every `long` argument in `@Scheduled` has a string alternative. Use them:

```java
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 25000, initialDelayString = "${producer.init-delay}")
public produce() {}
```

Comment: I apologize for the inaccurately worded question. I need to understand how to get the Long number from properties. I'll probably have to ask a new question.

Comment: @alexSerg but this is how you can get it. The code I showed in the answer will do it. 
If you want the Long itself, then use `@Value("${producer.init-delay}")`. It will do what you want

Comment: This does not answer the question...